# "Чел" українською

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як буде популярне зараз в російській слово "чел" (від "человек") українською? Можна сказати "чол" (від "чоловік"), але це все одно позначає лише осіб чоловічої статі.

Answer (score 7):

[Хлоп.](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF)

> 2. діал. Чоловік, хлопець.

Мої приклади:

- Що це за хлоп там тиняється?
- А цей хлоп добре на бубні навчений.
- Звідки цей хлоп до нас приблудився?

Answer (score 4):

У популярному вжитку в українській мові на сьогодні є слово "кент".

Наприклад, у [треці](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyEgjIts-wc) гурту Калуш "Тіпок" із більш як трьома мільйонами переглядів, є такі рядки:

> В падіку кент навалив кента
>
> Виснуть нібито стара вінда

Є версія, що "кент" походить від קענט (кент), що на їдиші [означає](https://www.duolingo.com/dictionary/Yiddish/%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%98/fffcacb1d138db1f4644d57112fca67a) "знати". І, відповідно, באקענט(אר) (бекент) — знайомий.

Українській притаманно позичати з їдишу (дивись, наприклад, "Тюремні сонети" Франка) не менше, ніж з російської, і є версія, що це слово було запозичене в Одесі.

Щодо "осіб лише чоловічої статі", то, мені здається, "чел" теж позначає здебільшого осіб чоловічої статі.

Answer (score 1):

Більш-менш нейтральними словами на позначення людини незалежно від статі є (на додачу до, звісно, слова *людина*) *особа*, *персона*, *індивід*. Слово *особа* часто на письмі скорочують до *ос.* (як-от *3 ос.*). Але я поки не бачу якихось ознак того, що скорочення *ос(а)* могло б з'явиться в розмовному спілкуванні, принаймні скоро (здається, слово особа і так достатньо коротке).

Якщо ж мова про ненейтральні (зокрема іронічні) слова, то можу запропонувати:

- *гаврик*,
- *шишка* (про впливову особу),
- *птах*, *птиця* (про впливову особу або людину високої про себе думки),
- *цяця* (про жінку, що чимось виділяється, наприклад вродою чи впливом).

(Всі слова взято з переліку синонімів до слова *особа* в [«Словниках України online» від УМІФ](https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/).)

Answer (score 0):

в російській, слово "чел" також має значення саме чоловічої статі, на приклад " молодой человек" відноситься лише до парубків. Тож напемне "чол" доволі точний переклад. Хоча, як на мене, подібний сленг не варто намагатись перекладати і вистачить лиш змінити вимову на україньську, як, наприклад, "окей".

Comment: *молодой человек* кажуть не тільки парубкам. Частину про *окей* не зрозумів. Як саме треба змінити вимову?

Comment: частина про окей в сенсі: в російській вимова через "є", тоді як в українській через "е"

Comment: а молодой человек, можеш хоч загуглити, звертаються так лиш до чоловіків

Comment: так, до чоловіків, але не тільки до парубків.

Comment: нуу, чоловіків середнього віку дуже рідко

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: парубком можна бути і в 80. Я з російськомовного регіону і "молодой человек" там вживали і для старших. Це залежало від того хто називав і з якою ціллю.

Comment: я з вами категорично не згоден, але якось не хочеться розводити про це срач, в кінці кінців, суті того про, що я писав у мершому своєму коментарі, вік не змінить.